# For loop with pair-wise conditions/variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, simulink

I have a question regarding the use of for-loops with pair-wise variables.

Right now I am using a loop:

```
For i=1:1:10
Code
End
```

Code executes a Simulink model. I need to introduce two variables into this model. One is Torque (A1–A10), another one is TriggerTime (B1-B10). But I need to use them in pair. So for instance I want to execute the model with A1,B1, i(1) conditions, the next iteration with A2,B2,i(2) and so on. I was thinking about something like:

```
TriggerTime= [B1 B2. ..B10]
Torque=[ A1 A2… A10]
YY = 1;
For i= 1:1:10
TriggerTime[1,YY];
Break torque[1,YY];
Y= Y +1;
Code
End
```

And purely in MATLAB I reckon this code will work (or not?). But when it comes to my Simulink model, it makes it a little bit more complicated:

**Error_message:**

[image: Error_message]

and

**Simulink_model_part:**

[image: Simulink_model_part]

I was trying to figure out how to manage these issues, but could not. I can see that it should be quite simple, but can’t understand how I can tweak the code.

Comment: Check the matlab-command set_param.

Comment: Thank you, Sardar. Unfortunately it did not work out. It still gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to answer the question about Simulink since so little information about the model is provided, but you have a few issues with the simple for loop that makes me think perhaps that's where the problem lies.

This is your example:

```
TriggerTime= [B1 B2. ..B10]
Torque=[ A1 A2… A10]
YY = 1;
For i= 1:1:10
TriggerTime[1,YY];
Break torque[1,YY];
Y= Y +1;
Code
End
```

These are some issues with this:

- You're not using the for variable `i` in the for loop.
- You are however manually incrementing a variable, `Y`, but that is not used either.
- The initialization of the for loop variable `i` contains a redundant 1 and should read simply `i=1:10`.
- You're not indenting the code inside the for loop, which decreases readability and increases risk for errors.
- You're trying to use square brackets, [], to access array elements when you should be using normal parenthesis, ().
- You're using a keyword, `[break][1]`, inside the for loop, which terminates the for loop.
- The initialization of the condition variables, `TriggerTime` and `Torque`, results in two 1D arrays, but you're expecting two 2D arrays inside the for loop since you're giving two indices, `[1,YY]`.

Try this for loop and see if it works better:

```
TriggerTime = [B1 B2 ... B10];
Torque = [A1 A2 ... A10];
for i = 1:10
    currentTriggerTime = TriggerTime(i);
    currentTorque = Torque(i);
    Code
end
```

Comment: Further to the above, `currentTriggerTime` and `currentTorque` are then the variables that should be used in the Simulink model, presumably called using `sim` (although as pointed out the OP hasn't posted enough information about how they are interacting with Simulink).

Comment: Thank you, Carlos.